# Как правильно присваивать элементы из аргумента?

Tags: javascript, dom

У меня есть функция, которая должна проверять  является ли первый элемент родителем для второго, но `child` не видит свойство `parentNode`. Как правильно присвоить этот аргумент со свойством?

```
function isParent(parent, child) {
    if (child.parentNode === parent) {
        console.log(true)
    } else {
        console.log(false)
    }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <article>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, odio omnesque ius cu, quo ex atqui antiopam. At detracto menandri eos. Duo in causae viderer, graeci <a href="#">reprehendunt</a> has in. Decore <mark>nemore</mark> philosophia te pro, nobis legere causae ex mei, odio putant mentitum ea ius. Vix nostro deserunt explicari eu.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
  </ul><span></span>
  <a href="#">Some link</a>
  <script src="app.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Покажите использование этой функции

Comment: 1. Создать функцию, которая принимает два элемента. Функция проверяет, является ли первый элемент родителем для второго:

isParent(parent, child);
isParent(document.body.children[0], document.querySelector('mark'));
// true так как первый див является родительским элементом для mark

isParent(document.querySelector('ul'), document.querySelector('mark'));
// false так ul НЕ является родительским элементом для mark
Функция принимает только DOM объекты.

Answer (score 0):

Я искал потомков свойством для детей. Если кого заинтересует ответ на этот вопрос, то `conatains` - свойство для потомков, а `parentNode` - свойство для прямых детей.

```
 function isParent(parent, child) {
      if (parent.contains(child)) {
        console.log(true);
      } else {
        console.log(false);
      }
    }
```